# Project Euler #12 in Racket

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, racket

[Problem here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12).

It's not exactly the brute force approach but I'm not using any sort of pre-calculated primes table, and I'm definitely not using the coprimality trick shown in the PE pdf. I'm finding the divisor count for each triangle number via its representation as a product of primes. More on it [here](http://mathschallenge.net/library/number/number_of_divisors).

I've written a bunch of similarly sized programs in Chicken Scheme before, and this is my 2nd Racket program.

Is there anything that I'm doing that isn't something a Racketeer would do? Am I reinventing anything that's already implemented?

```
#lang racket

(define (prime? n)
  (if (<= n 1)
      #f
      (not (ormap (lambda (x) (= (modulo n x) 0))
                  (stream->list (in-range 2 (add1 (truncate (sqrt n)))))))))

(define (next-prime start)
  (define (search candidate)
    (if (prime? candidate)
        candidate
        (search (add1 candidate))))
  (search (add1 start)))

(define (prime-factors n)
  (define (decompose num prime factors)
    (cond
      ([prime? num] (append factors (list num)))
      ([not (= 0 (modulo num prime))] (decompose num (next-prime prime) factors))
      (else (decompose (quotient num prime) prime (append factors (list prime))))))
  (if (= n 1)
      empty
      (decompose n (next-prime 1) empty)))

(define (remove-duplicates numbers)
  (define (remove numbers result)
    (cond
      ([empty? numbers] result)
      ([not (member (first numbers) result)]
       (remove (rest numbers) (append result (list (first numbers)))))
      (else
       (remove (rest numbers) result))))
  (remove numbers empty))

(define (divisor-count n)
  (let* ([factors (prime-factors n)]
         [no-duplicates-factors (remove-duplicates factors)])
    (apply * (map add1 (map (lambda (x)
                              (count (lambda (y) (= x y)) factors))
                            no-duplicates-factors)))))

(define (number->triangle-number n)
  (quotient (* n (add1 n))
            2))

(define (first-triangle-num-with property)
  (define (search candidate)
    (let ([triangle-candidate (number->triangle-number candidate)])
      (if (property triangle-candidate)
          triangle-candidate
          (search (add1 candidate)))))
  (search 1))
```

An answer is obtained via a call like:

```
(first-triangle-num-with (lambda (x) (>= (divisor-count x) 10)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## stream->list

Avoid `stream->list` on large lists.
In your `prime?` function it will create a (large)
list before passing it on to `ormap`.

There is a stream version of `ormap` - namedly `stream-ormap`, and
this will process the stream lazily - i.e. it will only generate
as many elements of the stream which are needed.

## next-prime

Another way to eliminate the recursion here is to combine
`stream-first` with `stream-filter` and `in-naturals` with
your `prime?` predicate, e.g.:

```
(stream-first (stream-filter prime? (in-naturals ...) ))
```

Not that recursion is bad, but using streams results in
a more declarative definition.

## append

I would avoid `append` in a Lisp or a Scheme.
I'm sure it's not efficient for use on lists.
`cons`, however, is always efficient, so in `prime-factors` you should
use:

```
(cons num factors)
```

instead of:

```
(append factors (list num))
```

You build the list in reverse order, but it won't matter
in this case.

## remove-duplicates

You are also using `append` here which should be avoided.
The standard definition again uses `cons`:

```
(define (remove-duplicates xs)
   -- if xs is empty, return xs
   -- else return x followed by remove-duplicates on the tail elements not equal to x
     (cons (head x)
           (remove-duplicates (filter (lambda (y) (not (eq? x y))) (tail xs))))
)
```

For short lists this is fine - but note that its running time is O(n^2).
If you need a better one, there is one available in the standard library:
[remove-duplicates](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) in the standard library. On longer lists it uses a hash - you can view the source here: [(link)](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/master/racket/collects/racket/list.rkt#L384)

## divisor-count

Honestly I had trouble understanding your `prime-factors` and `divisor-count` routines.

The conventional way of computing the number of divisors of a number *n* is:

1. find a prime divisor *p* of *n*
2. find the exponent *e* of the prime *p* in the factorization of *n*
3. repeat this process with *n* / *p^e* until *n* = 1

Then you have a list of primes and their exponents: (*p1*, *e1*), (*p2*, *e2*), etc.
and the number of divisors is:

```
(1+e1) * (1 + e2) * ...
```

How about this approach:

```
(define (divisor-count n)
  (apply * (map add1 (prime-exponents n))))

(define (prime-exponents n)
   -- if n == 1 return the empty list
   -- otherwise, find the first prime p dividing n
   -- find largest e s.t. p^e divides n
   -- return e and recurse on n / p^e   )
```

## first-triangle-number

This is another place where using streams can help:

1. Create a stream of triangle numbers
2. Filter the stream keeping only those with large divisor counts
3. Take the first element of the stream

i.e.:

```
(stream-first (stream-filter ... (stream-map ... (in-naturals 1))))
                                                 \___ 1, 2, ... __/
                                 \__ 1, 3, 6, 10, ...          __/
              \___ triangular numbers having #divisors >= 50  __/
\___ answer to the problem                                   __/
```

Note that `(in-naturals 1)` is an infinite stream.

## for, for/list

When you get comfortable using the `stream-` functions, look into
Racket's sequence comprehensions: `for`, `for/list`, `for/vector`, etc.

See http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html for more info.

Comment: I like that your answer is a critique, rather than a complete reimplementation, of the OP's program. Of course I still think my solution has less reinvention (which was what the OP asked for), but within the framework of what the OP coded, your comments are spot on.

Comment: Thanks! It's often sometimes hard to know what people are expecting when they post in this forum :-)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate review, I'll read it more carefully today.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you're reimplementing is [`divisors`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/number-theory.html?q=factorize#%28def._%28%28lib._math%2Fnumber-theory..rkt%29._divisors%29%29). Also, you can generate triangle numbers using [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) streams. Using these two things together, we have:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require srfi/41 math/number-theory)
(define naturals (stream-cons 1 (stream-map add1 naturals)))
(define triangles (stream-cons 0 (stream-map + naturals triangles)))
(for/first ((n (in-stream triangles))
            #:when (> (length (divisors n)) 500))
  (display n))
```

I'm sorry that this is nothing like your original program, but your question asked "Am I reinventing anything that's already implemented?", and it seems that pretty much everything in your program is indeed a reinvention. :-(

Comment: Whoa :O That's pretty awesome!